# html pages come scattered between pages when i print them with html2pdf library in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, html2pdf

html2pdf is printing a pdf but the write is choppy between pages how to solve?

this my code javascript if you need to html i can comment it,
any one have an idea ? please help me!

```
<script>
    
          window.onload = function () {
              document.getElementById("download")
                  .addEventListener("click", () => {
                      const invoice = this.document.getElementById("invoice");
                      console.log(invoice);
                      console.log(window);
                      var opt = {
                          margin: 1,
                          filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                          image: { type: 'png', quality: 0.98 },
                          html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                          jsPDF: { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'landscape'}
                          // p\init : pt   unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' 
                      };
                      html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
                  })
          }
              </script>
```

that is screenshot from pdf for more clarification

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSdId.png